# What does this code snippet do? ('struct foo{struct foo *var;};')

Tags: c, struct

I've come across some snippet of code while searching for garbage collecting in C. I read this [article](https://maplant.com/gc.html) whose title is "Writing a Simple Garbage Collector in C".

And this `Struct` is eye-catching: (for me)

```
typedef struct header {
    unsigned int    size;
    struct header   *next;
} header_t;
```

From what I know, the `typedef struct header` is used to save some keystrokes so if using the `struct`, you'll just type

```
header_t hdr;
```

instead of:

```
struct header hdr;
```

However, I don't understand what the 3rd line does:

```
struct header    *next;
```

Comment: This creates a member `next` with type `struct header *` (a pointer).

Comment: The asterisk, in this context, denotes a *pointer*. Pointers are an integral and very important part of C, and any decent book, tutorial or class should have covered it.

Comment: `struct header` is the name of the type - which is why you need to make a `typedef` in the first place. Inside the block, the typedef doesn't exist yet, so you have to use `struct header` to refer to that type. `struct header    *next;` here means the same thing that it would inside any other struct declaration, and the same (well, analogous) thing that it would mean with any other typename before the `*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'm really satisfied by now hahahhahahaha....

Comment: Please note that this is *not a discussion forum*. We aren't interested in conversational language; and if you found a similar question you should a) explicitly link it, and b) explicitly tell us exactly why the answer does not satisfy you. Stack Overflow is, as such, also not really the right place to learn the fundamentals of the language, or to understand somebody else's code; please refer to tutorials, documentation etc.

Comment: ok, I got it! ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct is a node in a **linked list**.

The pointer element in the struct can point to another instance of the struct.  This allows you to dynamically allocate memory for an instance of the struct and put it at the end (or the beginning) of the list.  You'll have a pointer to the first element, commonly referred to as the *head* of the list.  Then you can traverse the list by following the `next` pointers until you find one set to `NULL` which indicates the end of the list.

Comment: Oh now I know  what is it called thank you so much for the answer!